# How to change Gradle\SDK settings when opening Android Studio project from a different PC

Tags: android, android-studio

I Copied my Android Studio project from my work PC and copied it to my home PC.
When I opened the project I got the following error:

> Failed to import Gradle project: Could not fetch model of type
>   'IdeaProject' using Gradle distribution
>   'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.6-bin.zip'. Build
>   file
>   'C:\Users\Tom\AndroidStudioProjects\CongressProject\Congress\build.gradle'
>   line: 9 A problem occurred evaluating project ':Congress'. A problem
>   occurred evaluating project ':Congress'. The SDK directory 'D:\Program
>   Files\Android\android-studio\sdk' does not exist.

I guess that's because all my SDK\JDK and all other settings are in different locations in my work PC and home PC.
I get this error all the time I try to rebuild my project.

How do I fix this so I can work on the same project from home and work?
I want to make it easy to copy the project from my 2 different PC's.

thanks!

Comment: Can you create the folder on disk D:\ like on your work computer? However, i also found two similar issues on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17125175/gradle-build-errors-after-updating-android-studio and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17678289/android-studio-gradle-build-error-cant-locate-sdk-and-compile-server. I guess they'll work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a similar question in:
[Gradle build errors after updating Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17125175/gradle-build-errors-after-updating-android-studio)

in the local.properties file in the root of the project, change the sdk.dir value.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else running into Gradle issues after updating Android Studio:

Go to File > Project Structure > Project.

My Gradle version and Android plug in version did not match, which was causing my issue. If you make a change here, make sure you also update your top-level Gradle file with the same version like so: **classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:*some version number*'**