# Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I want to import the sample project from the github. I have downloaded the whole package into zip , extracted the zip , and there are several folders in it. The one I want to import is sample app .

Now when Ever I tried to import it I get the following error

> **Error:(1, 0) SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.**

I have searched many link on stackoverflow. But got nothing. Please help me.

Comment: You need to create an environment variable named ANDROID_HOME with your sdk path as value. Which OS are you using?

Comment: using android studio or eclipse?

Comment: I have android sdk in E drive , the path is as below :
E:\AndroidStudio\SDK
so for the variable name I have given, :  ANDROID_HOME
and for the path , i have copy pasted the path :  E:\AndroidStudio\SDK

Comment: android studio for sure

Comment: Try to generate `local.properties` file with: `android update project -p .` in the root project directory. Then, add  `sdk.dir=E:\AndroidStudio\SDK` to it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where does local.properties go for android project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20673378/where-does-local-properties-go-for-android-project)

Comment: I have checked its there the path is correct

Comment: set your ANDROID_HOME and PATH variables - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26356359/error-android-home-is-not-set-and-android-command-not-in-your-path-you-must-ful