# How to find the sdk.dir location on command-line environment?

Tags: android, gradle, command-line

I  create an android project on the command line, with gradle. But without Android Studio.
I get a error message:

```
The SDK directory 'C:\Android_SDK\sdk' does not exist
```

As cause I find the entry in `local.properties`:

```
sdk.dir=C\:\\Android_SDK\\sdk
```

I found further, this entry should [e.g.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28299460/11348074) be changed to:

```
sdk.dir=C\:\\Users\\<realusername>\\AppData\Local\\Android\\sdk
```

or [according](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30164138/11348074) :

```
sdk.dir=C\:\\AndroidStudio\\SDK
```

and something like that. <realusername> is to be replace with my user name. But all that directories does not exist. If I create a directory, I get the error:

```
failed to find target with hash string 'android-23' in: C:\Users\<realusername>\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
```

That means in this folder are some files and folders expected.

My **question** is, how can I detect which directory on my system corresponds to `sdk.dir`? Or which files and folders are expected for gradle when specifying the directory for sdk.dir? So I can determine which directory to name.

I have already installed numerous binaries and libraries necessary for Android. And I suspect I may already have the files I need. Therefore I do not want to install the Android Studio package additionally. If I know what content is expected from sdk.dir, I can also specify the path correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I determined the identification as follows:

**Determination by content:**

- Search for the file `android.bat`. The root folder of `tools/android.bat` is the `sdk.dir` folder.
- Or search for the directory `build-tools` with (the build-tools) subdirectories like `23.0.1`, `26.0.1`, or something like that. The parent directory of `build-tools` is the `sdk.dir` directory.

**Print out the sdk.dir location:**

Run `android.bat` which is located in the `/tools` folder. This opens the SDK Manager GUI. On the top left area of the Manager you can check the hint "SDK Path:". There is written the absolute path to the `sdk.dir`.