# How to solve Android Studio problems?

Tags: bash, android-studio, react-native, sdk

Hello I have installed in my Ubuntu Android Studio with the intention of using them SDK with React Native, Cordova, Phonegap, etc.

I have searched other questions on this site and tried the solutions they offered, but the result so far is that what I show next, after 10 days installing and testing I have decided to ask my question.

I made the installation according to the official page of Android Studio and in several ways, but I can not get it to work.

Now I have the installation of the following way, to avoid problems of permissions:

- Copy the downloaded folder from Android Studio to `/usr/local/`
- For the SDK I chose a folder in my personal folder `/home/charly/Android/sdk/`

  - Install the necessary libraries for 32-bit `sudo apt-get install libc6: i386 libncurses5: i386 libstdc ++ 6: i386 lib32z1 lib32bz2-1.0`
- To run the Android Studio installer, I placed it in the Android Studio location in the bin folder using the terminal:
  `cd/usr/local/android-studio/bin`

  - Execute: `./studio.sh`
- I edit the .bashrc file: sudo vim `~/.bashrc` and add the following to the end of the file:

  export PATH=${PATH}:/home/charly/Android/sdk/tools
  export PATH=${PATH}:/home/charly/Android/sdk/platform-tools

  - Install:

  sudo apt-get install lib32stdc ++ 6
  sudo apt-get install lib32z1

  - When I run `android sdk`  and `android avd` the answer is: Order «android» not found. When should I take the SDK Manager and AVD Manager, respectively.

Also, there is another problem and when executing `printenv ANDROID_HOME` the result of the console is: `/opt/android-sdk/` And in this folder is not Android Studio.

When I try to run an Android application from React Native: react-native run-android I get an error:

```
S server already running.
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug) ...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ': app'.
> The SDK directory '/ opt / android-sdk' does not exist.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

Command failed: ./gradlew installDebug

Error: Command failed: ./gradlew installDebug
    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js: 611: 11)
    at Object.execFileSync (child_process.js: 629: 13)
    at runOnAllDevices (/home/charly/proyec/App/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runAndroid/runAndroid.js:299:19)
    at buildAndRun (/home/charly/proyect/App/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runAndroid/runAndroid.js:135:12)
    at isPackagerRunning.then.result (/home/charly/proyect/App/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runAndroid/runAndroid.js:65:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal / process / next_tick.js: 68: 7)
```

How can I solve these problems?
Why does it tell me that SDKs do not exist in `'/opt/android-sdk'` if I set up .bashrc to say they are in `home/charly/Android/sdk`?

Maybe the question is extensive, but I want to explain the whole installation and they can see the mistakes I've made in this one.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable in one of your bash startup scripts. This is explained in detail [elsewhere on Stackoverflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26256279/how-to-set-android-home-path-in-ubuntu)

Alternatively, you could [add a local.properties file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20673378/where-does-local-properties-go-for-android-project) to configure the SDK location.