# React Native Android SDK Supported Version Not Found Mac

Tags: android, react-native

I'm new to React Native. My goal is to build the Android.
There has been lots of solutions for this particular problem, but I believe I've followed almost of them already.

Here's my doctor cli result:

```
Common
 ✓ Node.js
 ✓ npm
 ✓ Watchman - Used for watching changes in the filesystem when in development mode

Android
 ✓ JDK
 ✓ Android Studio - Required for building and installing your app on Android
 ✖ Android SDK - Required for building and installing your app on Android
   - Versions found: 28.0.2, 28.0.3, 29.0.0, 29.0.2, 29.0.3, 30.0.2
   - Version supported: Not Found
 ✓ ANDROID_HOME

iOS
 ✓ Xcode - Required for building and installing your app on iOS
 ✓ CocoaPods - Required for installing iOS dependencies
 ● ios-deploy - Required for installing your app on a physical device with the CLI

Errors:   1
Warnings: 1
```

As you can see, the SDK can be found, but not the `supported version`, apparently.

What I did so far:

1. added `local.properties` https://stackoverflow.com/a/54234228/3231194
2. configured properly the `/.bash_profile` thing.
3. installed Android NDK Side by Side, and other required stuff for Android.
4. installed Android API 30, 10.0(Q)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Switch to `SDK Platforms` on Preferences settings and install version 28, 29, 30. Then try to run again. Hope It's helpful.

Comment: Thanks for this. Although this answer should help, I've never tried it. But I just wanna close this question and I'd like to add more info: the doctor-cli does not really help. I mean even though it displays no supported version, I still made it running.

Comment: @GlennPosadas Yes. It's still warning to you by following a guideline. DoctorCli should be use to check error if you are facing any problem.

Comment: This doesn't help BTW.